# vuejs input witdh mask new money

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vuejs and frankly I couldn't find what I wanted to do. When I found it, it didn't work for me.

I have an input and I want the value entered in this input to be written with the value of "MONEY", but I could not succeed.

example:
When 1000 is written to the input, when the input is exited
I want 1,000,00 to be written.
[image]

```
"vue": "^2.6.12",
```

Person.vue

```
<CurrencyInput v-bind:model-value="value" :options="{ currency: 'EUR' }" />
<CurrencyInput :model-value="value" :options="{ currency: 'EUR' }" />
<CurrencyInput v-model="value" :options="{ currency: 'EUR' }"/>
<CurrencyInput :value="value" :options="{ currency: 'EUR' }"/>

<script>
import CurrencyInput from "../tools/CurrencyInput";

export default {
    components: {
        CurrencyInput
    },
    data() {
        return {
            value: 123456,
}
},
}
</script>
```

tools/CurrencyInput.Vue

```
<template>
    <input ref="inputRef" :value="formattedValue" />
</template>

<script>
import useCurrencyInput from "vue-currency-input";

export default {
    name: "CurrencyInput",
    props: {
        modelValue: Number,
        options: Object,
    },
    setup(props) {
        const { formattedValue, inputRef } = useCurrencyInput(props.options);

        return { inputRef, formattedValue };
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-currency-input it has a bunch of options, masking whilst maintaining good UX is not a simple couple of lines

Comment: well it can't do what i want. I added what I want to do as an image to the question.

Comment: Deleting zeros after the comma is a problem for me

Comment: example: 100,00 she makes corrections and the result is 100

Comment: Not if you use the correct options: https://imgur.com/a/vlY5Qx2

Comment: so how do i do this

Comment: How did you make the component work in vue 2? I have not been able. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74469780/how-to-use-vue-currency-input-in-vue-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [vue-currency-input](https://npmjs.com/package/vue-currency-input) with the following options:

```
{
    locale: 'nl-NL',
    currency: 'GBP',
    currencyDisplay: 'hidden',
    precision: 2,
    hideCurrencySymbolOnFocus: true,
    hideGroupingSeparatorOnFocus: true,
    hideNegligibleDecimalDigitsOnFocus: true,
    autoDecimalDigits: false,
    exportValueAsInteger: false,
    autoSign: false,
    useGrouping: true
}
```

The input will be masked like the following:

[image]

View the [docs](https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/) and [playground](https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/playground.html) for further options.

Comment: So, can't I write it in component instead of bind?

Comment: not sure what you mean, I've linked to the docs on how to use it there is an example there which uses a custom component https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/guide.html#creating-a-custom-component

Comment: I'm using the same as here, but I want to define "props options" instead of ````:options="{ currency: 'GBP' }" ```.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-currency-input-vue-3-example-5l51f?from-embed=&file=/src/CurrencyInput.vue)

Comment: pass the prop `:options="options"`, https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-currency-input-vue-3-example-forked-90loo?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: instead of doing that i want to make main component options. "CurrencyInput.vue"

Comment: Why is the initial value null, although there is "value:1234" in the data, the input is empty at the beginning

Comment: I wouldn't know without seeing your code, in the link above I've set the value and it's not null, don't forget to upvote and accept if this answer helped

Comment: Although I tried the following inputs one by one, it does not show the "value" value at the beginning in any way. Where am I going wrong or how can I fix it? Is it difficult to write an example?

Comment: How did you make the component work in vue 2? I have not been able. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74469780/how-to-use-vue-currency-input-in-vue-2

Answer (score 0):

#### - Requirements -

The easiest way to achieve this (without dependencies) is to stay away from `v-model` and rather refer to the manual events which are:

- `@input`
- `@focus`
- `@blur`

and binding the value itself via the more static `:value="value"` approach. This way we have way more control over the output without vue-magic interfering

#### - Process -

0. Initially you want to have the input to be of type `"text"` as you want to display the dot/comma notation of the money.
1. On focus you want to change the type to number and remove the comma/dot notations.
2. on blur you want to switch back to the initial displaying style. This is achieved by using [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat).
3. on input you want to save the new value into a number ref.

### - CodeSandbox -

[> Here you can see the concept in action <](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-money-converter-input-no-t3qro)