# How to use vue-currency-input in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, input, vuejs2, currency

I'm trying to inplement the pluggin [`vue-currency-input`](https://npmjs.com/package/vue-currency-input) using vue 2.6.

```
"vue": "^2.6.12",
```

https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/guide.html

However in the documentation only details this information:

> Compatibility
>
> Vue Currency Input 3.x requires either Vue 2.7 or Vue 3. For Vue 2.6
> or earlier, please use Vue Currency Input 2.x with the Vue Composition
> API plugin.

What does mean "use with the Vue Composition API plugin."?

I installed these packages:

```
npm install vue-currency-input
npm install @vue/composition-api
```

Then in the `main.js` file I added the following lines after `import Vue from "vue";` :

```
import VueCompositionAPI from "@vue/composition-api";
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI);
```

Then I create the component CurrencyInput.vue with this:

```
<template>
  <input ref="inputRef" type="text" />
</template>

<script>
import { useCurrencyInput } from "vue-currency-input";

export default {
  name: "oCurrencyInput",
  props: {
    value: Number,
    options: Object,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const { inputRef } = useCurrencyInput(props.options);

    return { inputRef };
  },
};
</script>
```

Then I tried to use it as normally we do.

```
<template>
  <CurrencyInput
    v-model="value"
    :options="{ currency: 'EUR' }"
  />
</template>

<script>
import CurrencyInput from './CurrencyInput'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { CurrencyInput },
  data: () => ({ value: 1234 })
}
</script>
```

Finally, it is not working and showing these warnings:

```
 WARNING  Compiled with 5 warnings                                                                                                                                          10:02:52 PM
 warning  in ./node_modules/vue-currency-input/dist/index.mjs

"export 'computed' was not found in 'vue'

 warning  in ./node_modules/vue-currency-input/dist/index.mjs

"export 'getCurrentInstance' was not found in 'vue'

 warning  in ./node_modules/vue-currency-input/dist/index.mjs

"export 'ref' was not found in 'vue'

 warning  in ./node_modules/vue-currency-input/dist/index.mjs

"export 'version' was not found in 'vue'

 warning  in ./node_modules/vue-currency-input/dist/index.mjs

"export 'watch' was not found in 'vue'
```

Also, I tried to add @vue/composition-api in some way like this:

```
<template>
  <input ref="inputRef" type="text" />
</template>

<script>
import { useCurrencyInput } from "vue-currency-input";
import { ref, reactive } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default {
  name: "oCurrencyInput",
  props: {
    modelValue: value,
    options: Object,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const { inputRef } = ref(useCurrencyInput(props.options));

    return { inputRef };
  },
};
</script>
```

Still not working. Finally, I saw [vuejs input witdh mask new money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68883060/vuejs-input-witdh-mask-new-money) but I could not find an answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Compatibility
>
> Vue Currency Input 3.x requires either Vue 2.7 or Vue 3. For Vue 2.6 or earlier, please use Vue Currency Input 2.x with the Vue Composition API plugin.

You are using Vue 2.6

So instead of `npm install vue-currency-input`, you must use `npm i vue-currency-input@2.5.1`

> What does mean "use with the Vue Composition API plugin."?

Yes, it means installing and using `@vue/composition-api` [docs](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api)

You also should not use current documentation. I'm not able to find the docs for 2.x (as [the site](https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/)) only have a link for v1.x docs but you can easily read the docs in Markdown format directly on Github. [Here are the docs for v2.x](https://github.com/dm4t2/vue-currency-input/tree/v2/docs)

Comment: Your answer should be in the installation guide. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Its is, read the yellow box https://dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/guide.html#guide

Comment: @LawrenceCherone it is not in the link you shared  dm4t2.github.io/vue-currency-input/guide.html#guide. `npm install vue-currency-input` installs version for Vue3 instead of Vue2.

Comment: @JotaPardo using npm is a separate question..  do `npm i vue-currency-input@2.5.1`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you can see that was exactly the same answer of Michal Levý it is not a separate question. It is the original question.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone nowhere in the link you sent me does it say to use `npm i vue-currency-input@2.5.1`